# How to set Client Characteristic Configuration on Android for BLE descriptor?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

Hi I am making an Anrdoid BLE App which can communicate with Arduino nano 33 IOT.
My notification callback method is never called, so I ask question on stackoverflow few days ago. and someone has answer me that my Arduino BLE descriptor is clearly states **notifications and indications are disabled** [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72613800/android-between-arduino-ble-communication-oncharacteristicchanged-not-call-probl). So I tried to found how to set enable notification and indication. As soon as I searched on google, I realized there is no way to set descriptor on Arduino. And also someone said I have to set notification and indication on Android. [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626516/how-to-enable-notification-and-indications-on-arduino-nano-33-iot-ble-descriptor)

But I can't still find some code which can set notification and indication on Android.
I thought the codes below can set descriptor's notification and indication, but it didn't work.

```
MainThreadPrint("1 - btGattCharacteristic success");
BluetoothGattDescriptor bluetoothGattDescriptor = btGattCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("beca6057-955c-4f8a-e1e3-56a1633f04b1"));
MainThreadPrint("2 - Descriptor found! : beca6057-955c-4f8a-e1e3-56a1633f04b1");                          
bluetoothGattDescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
MainThreadPrint("3 - Descriptor ENABLED.");
btGatt.writeDescriptor(bluetoothGattDescriptor);
MainThreadPrint("4 - descriptor setting finished.");
```

So how to set descriptor's value for enable notification and indication on Android APP?
(descriptor value : the red underline in the picture.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable notifications on a remote device, you need to use the function [setCharacteristicNotification()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#setCharacteristicNotification(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic,%20boolean)). This is described in further details in the links below:-

- [Subscribe to a BLE GATT notification on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068673/subscribe-to-a-ble-gatt-notification-android/27075669#27075669)
- [BLE programming on Android - The complete Tutorial (Enable notifications)](https://intersog.com/blog/code/how-to-work-properly-with-bt-le-on-android/)
- [The ultimate guide to Android BEL development (Enabling and disabling notifications)](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)